# Click event handling for outlook items like mail, contact, calendar and task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to implement outlook addin to access details of Outlook items like mail, calendar, task and contact.

I have created sample addin and added many custom items to context menu. but what i now need is, if i click on outlook contact then context menu have only contact related custom item(e.g. Contact Name), all other either disable or removed from context menu (e.g. Event Name).

sample code is as below:

```
public void PacktMenuItem_ItemContextMenuDisplay(Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar PacktCommandBar, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection Selection)
        {
            // Commadbarpopup control to context menu item
            Office.CommandBarPopup callBarPopUp = (Office.CommandBarPopup)PacktCommandBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Type.Missing, "Custom Menu Item 1", PacktCommandBar.Controls.Count + 1, Type.Missing);
            // Set the tag value for the menu
            callBarPopUp.Tag = "PacktCustomMenuItem1";
            // Caption for the context menu item
            callBarPopUp.Caption = "custom items";
            // Set it to visible
            callBarPopUp.Visible = true;

            //item 1
            Office.CommandBarButton callButton2 = (Office.CommandBarButton)callBarPopUp.Controls.Add(1, missing, missing, missing, true);
            callButton2.Caption = "Contact Name";
            callButton2.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(Callxx2);

            //item 2
            Office.CommandBarButton callButton3 = (Office.CommandBarButton)callBarPopUp.Controls.Add(1, missing, missing, missing, true);
            callButton3.Caption = "Event Name";
            callButton3.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(Callxx3);
        }
```

Please guide.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found one good post, which help me to solve my query..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Thanks to microsoft..;)